# Таймер обратного отсчета

Tags: php

Юзер кликает, на странице появляется обратный отсчет, когда время прошло, можно опять кликать. Если время не прошло, выводит сообщение "подождите".

Подскажите, как реализовать. Желательно куском кода т.к. только учусь, еще многого не знаю. Заранее спасибо.

И еще, использовать нужно только php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<button id="start">Чтобы получить ссылку кликайте :)</button>
<span id="timerValue"></span>
<div id="result">Подождите...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var timerInterval; //переменная для интервала нашего таймера
    onload = function() {
        var start = document.getElementById("start");
        start.onclick = timerStart;
    }
    function timerStart() {
        // поменяем текс кнопки...
        // используем переменную this, т.к. в ней сейчас и хранится наша кнопка....
        this.innerHTML = "Ожидание...";
        timerInterval = setInterval("timerAction()", 1000);
    }

    function timerAction() {
        var timerValue = document.getElementById("timerValue");
        if(timerValue.innerHTML == "")  {//если значение таймера пустое...   
             timerValue.innerHTML = 30;
        }
        else if(timerValue != "0"){
             //для начала извлечем целочисленое значение....
             var seconds = parseInt(timerValue.innerHTML);
             timerValue.innerHTML = seconds - 1; //уменьшаем на секунду...
        }
        else {
            // все, таймер свое отбегал :)
            // теперь необходимо "убить" интервал...
            removeInterval(timerInterval);

            // но сначала уберем 'Подождите...'
            var result = document.getElementById("result");
            result.innerHTML = '';

            // для полноты картины - изменим текст кнопки...
            var button = document.getElementById("start");
            button.innerHTML = "Готово...";

            // терь например создадим какуюто ссылку и кинем в div result...
            var link = document.createElement("link");
            link.href = "http://somePage.html"; //тут href нашей ссылки...
            link.innerHTML = "Вот ваша ссылка...";
            result.appendChild(link);

            // осталось сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходило...
            button.onclick = ""; //как видно делается это очень просто :)
            return;
        }
    }
</script>
```

*Если правильно понял, то примерно вот так вот...

Возможно где-то есть какието ошибки, но если и так то они незначительны...*

Comment: <code>только на пхп.. я думаю это должно выглядеть так: 
echo '<button id="start">Чтобы получить ссылку кликайте :)</button>
<span id="timerValue"></span>
...........
</script>
';

Comment: Только на php вы этого не сделаете никак каГбы...<br>Каким волшебством вы собираете делать таймер?xD<br>И какая разница как задействовать скрипт, по факту всеравно юзается JS

Answer (score 0):

Эм... Может я, конечно, не профи, но только на php такое сделать, я думаю, не получится... нет вообще можно, но тогда надо столько же страниц, сколько и цифр + куча редиректов. Такое можно сделать (и проще будет) на JS. Я не разбирался в JS, поэтому не могу ничего сказать. Вот [ссылка](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=606), буду рад, если поможет как-то.

Comment: Все кроме задающего вопрос обсуждают :)

Comment: ТС уже ищет книгу или видеоуроки по JavaScript :)

Comment: видимо так оно и есть :)

Answer (score 0):

**Исправлено:**

```
session_start();

$timer = 10 - (time() - $_SESSION['time']);
if($timer > 0){
    echo "подождите ".$timer." секунд";
}else{
    ?><a href="?start=true">нажать для обратного остчета</a><?
}
//запускаем таймер
if($_GET['start'] && $timer <=0){
$_SESSION['time'] = time();
}
```

Comment: если на php - не ущербно и без бубнов и костра это сделать невозможно!<br> И так ТС пришел к JavaScript'у xDDD

Comment: ща накатаю.. без особых извращений )

Comment: Костер разведен, приступим к ритуалу.... xD<br>Единственно что пришло в голову - генерить страницу и чтобы пользователь кликал 30 раз на ссылку <a href="lol">Уменьшить таймер на 1 секунду</a> xDDD

Answer (score 0):

*© костер разведен*

Раз, любой файл

```
Ваша ссылка:
<iframe src="/getlink.php?linkid=15" style="width: 200px;height: 40px;"></iframe>
```

Два, getlink.php

```
$links = array(); // а где хотите берите, хоть из файла, хоть из БД
$timeout = 5;// sec
if (!empty($links[@$_GET['linkid']])) {
  @ob_end_clean();
  echo 'wait ';
  @flush();
  for ($i = $timeout; $i > 0; $i--) {
    sleep(1);
    echo $i.' ';
    @flush();
    }
  echo '<a href="'.$links[@$_GET['linkid']].'">your link</a>';
  @flush();
  } else die('link not found');
```

Plain PHP, между прочим.

Comment: Это почему?) просто раз в секунду делаем вывод и flush, данные уходят клиенту и сразу отображаются. PHPCast смотрите, у него так mp3-streaming организован =)

Comment: <small><i>Эх, спалился, неуспел удалить коммент :)</i></small>

Comment: Он мне вощемта еще и на почту пришел например)

Comment: <small><i>
Да но так бы я мог написать что я такого не писал :D
</i></small>

Comment: по моему мы малость увлеклись.. про автообновление в вопросе ни слова ;)

Comment: а это:<b>появляется обратный отсчет</b>?

Comment: запустите мой пример и увидите.. он реально появляется ) но нигде не сказано, что он должен обновлятся ежесекундно ) обновил страницу, посмотрел сколько осталось и дальше спать )